# how to find and replace text in richtextbox

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# windows form, that does the following:

I have a `RichTextbox` that displays the contents of a text file.

I managed to build a search box with search button for the user to search for a specific text in this file. However, I want also to create a Find textbox and button to allow the user to replace that found text with new text he/she entered in the textbox and clicked replace button. How can I do that replace text? ... Thank you.

Here is the code for the search text:

```
 private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int index = 0;
     var temp = richTextArea.Text;
     richTextArea.Text = "";
     richTextArea.Text = temp;

     while (index < richTextArea.Text.LastIndexOf(textBoxSearch.Text))
     {
         richTextArea.Find(textBoxSearch.Text, index, richTextArea.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
         richTextArea.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;

         index = richTextArea.Text.IndexOf(textBoxSearch.Text, index) + 1;
     }
 }
```

[wnform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcRc4.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have an efficient answer for you, here:

```
    public static void QuickReplace(RichTextBox rtb, String word, String word2)
    {
        rtb.Text = rtb.Text.Replace(word, word2);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            QuickReplace(richTextBox1, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
    }
```

Replace `richTextBox1` with your `RichTextBox` `Control`, and replace `textBox1` & `textBox2` with your `TextBox` `Controls`

This replaces **ALL** desired text found in a `RichTextBox`

I made this code specifically for this kind of **Operation**.

If you would like, I can provide code for replacing text from another form, i.e. just like **Notepad**.

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all occurences of search word in text:

```
richTextArea.Text = richTextArea.Text.Replace(textBoxSearch.Text, replaceTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Sure, however, I was trying to replace images (fig1.png) with a new name. I have more than one image, besides if you search for "fig" and do the replace with your new text it will replace it for the images and for any other word that contains "fig" .. is there a way to fix that ... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You have a text like this: "fig1.img some text figo fig1.txt fig3.img."
You want only fig1.img and fig3.img to be changed?

Comment: Yes, I want only to replace the image name "fig" with the new name, however, the numbers stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have added two buttons, one to load the contents of file onto the rich text box and another one to Find and Replace the text and write the replaced contents to file again.

```
private void Load_File_Contents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Below code will read the file and set the rich textbox with the contents of file
            string filePath = @"C:\New folder\file1.txt";
            richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void ReplaceAndWriteToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\New folder\file1.txt";

            //Find the "find" text from the richtextbox and replace it with the "replace" text
            string find = txtFind.Text.Trim(); //txtFind is textbox and will have the text that we want to find and replace
            string replace = txtReplace.Text.Trim(); //txtReplace is text and it will replace the find text with Replace text
            string newText = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(find, replace);
            richTextBox1.Text = newText;

            //Write the new contents of rich text box to file
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, richTextBox1.Text.Trim());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thank you. I did the load file using filedialog method and your solution is working fine as well, thank you, however,  I was trying to replace images (fig1.png) with a new name. I have more than one image, besides if you search for "fig" and do the replace with your new text it will replace it for the images and for any other word that contains "fig" .. is there a way to fix that ... Thanks again for your help.